# Remove duplicates from a given string in Java using recusrion

Tags: java, string, recursion

I am getting an error in output as i need to give spaces in function calling of strchk in new StringBuilder("     ")
to get the output printed whereas it should be like new StringBuilder("")
I had also tried an online compiler it gives the same error
This is the input code

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        String abc="appnacolllege";
        Strchk(abc, 0, new StringBuilder("     "),new boolean[26]);
    }


    public static void Strchk (String abc,int i,StringBuilder str,boolean stroc[] ) 
      {
       if(i==str.length())
       {System.out.println(str);
       return;}
       char currChar=abc.charAt(i);
       if(stroc[currChar-'a']==true)
         //duplicate
       Strchk(abc, i+1, str, stroc);      
       else
       {
       stroc[currChar-'a']=true;
       Strchk(abc, i+1, str.append(currChar), stroc);
       }
    } 
}
```

Comment: what's the error? I've tried it and it's working

Comment: @Erwin Error is it should be new StringBuilder("")  like this but when i did this it does not gives the output

Comment: Could you please post a stack trace so we can see the error you are getting?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just a side-note, because your question has been answered. Please don't format you code like that. It's utterly unreadable

Answer (score 0):

There's a small bug in `Strchk` function. The base condition should be when `i` is equal to `abc.length()` not `str.length()`.  The function should be like this:

```
public static void Strchk (String abc, int i, StringBuilder str, boolean[] stroc)
{
    if( i==abc.length() ) {
        System.out.println(str);
        return;
    }
    char currChar=abc.charAt(i);
    if(stroc[currChar - 'a'])
        //duplicate
        Strchk(abc, i+1, str, stroc);
    else
    {
        stroc[currChar-'a']=true;
        Strchk(abc, i+1, str.append(currChar), stroc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've re-written your code, and removed the requirement for the `stroc` parameter.
Is this the process you're looking for?

Only append unique characters.

```java
void strchk(String string, int index, StringBuilder builder) {
    if (index >= string.length()) {
        System.out.println(builder);
        return;
    }
    char character = string.charAt(index);
    if (!builder.toString().contains(String.valueOf(character))) {
        strchk(string, index + 1, builder.append(character));
    } else {
        strchk(string, index + 1, builder);
    }
}
```

Output

```
apncoleg
```